# "Simple" edge - line - detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-recognition, edge-detection, hough-transform

At image i need find "table" - simple rectangle.
Problem is with edge recognition, because potencial photos will be "dark".
I tried edge - sobel, canny, log, .... - recognition and after that Hough transformation and line finding. But this algorithms are not enough for this task.
Something what can help me:
- it is rectangle!, only in perspective view (something like fitting perspective rectangle?)
- that object MUST cover atleast for example 90% of photo (i know i need looking near photo edges)
- that rectangle have fast same color (for example wood dining table)
- i need find atleast "only" 4 corners..(but yes, better will be find the edges of that table)

I know how for example sobel, canny or log algorithms works and Hough as well. And naturally those algorithms fail at dark or non-contrast images. But is there some another method for example based at "fitting"?
Images showing photo i can get (you see it would be dark) and what i need find:
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

and this is really "nice" picture (without noise). I tested it on more noise pictures and the result was..simply horrible..
Result of this picture with actual algorithm log (with another ones it looks same):
[image: image 3]
[image: image 4]
I know image and edge recognition is not simple challenge but are there some new better methods or something like that what i can try to use?
In one of posts in here i found LSD algorithm. It seems very nice descripted and it seems it is recognizing really nice straight lines as well. Do you think it would be better to use it insted of the canny or sobel detection?
Another solution will be corner detection, on my sample images it works better but it recognize too much points and there will problem with time..i will need to connect all the points and "find" the table..

Another solution: 
I thought about point to point mapping. That i will have some "virtual" table and try to map that table above with that "virtual" table (simple 2d square in painting :] )..But i think point to point mapping will give me big errors or it will not working.

Does someone have any advice what algorithm use to?
I tried recognize edges in FIJI and then put the edge detected image in matlab, but with hough it works bad as well..:/..

What do you think it would be best to use? In short i need find some algorithm working on non contrast, dark images.

Comment: This is not a "really nice" picture. If there are few pictures (<100) then spend something like 90 min. on doing this manually. Otherwise you should better control the lighting conditions. The table is illuminated very uneven, with the back part being very dark and just barely distinguishable from the counter. Image processing is hard already, start by optimizing the picture acquisition.

Comment: Would also be interested in a solution for this, canny etc wont really work well.. :( But you've got some nice ideas under "Something what can help me:"... I'll try to remember those ideas for my own approaches as they are good ones :-) Upvote for it

Comment: I was talking few months ago about this with my professor on university (he is a expert on image recognition, etc). He adviced me graphcut algoritm. Then i had some program about image recognition in medicine and we was working with graphcut (there are 2 versions, i do not remember now exactly, its about 5months ago) but one version of graphcut is working with intensity of pixels and own pixels and the second one is working with texture. I see graphcut like a relatively quick method with very good results of recognition. And then they adviced me watershed method. that it could be good as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try some modified [snakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model) algorithm:

you parameterize your rectangle with 4 points and initialize them somewhere in the image corners. Then you move the points towards image features using some optimization algorithm (e.g. gradient descent, simulated annealing, etc.).

The image features could be a combination of edge features (e.g. sobel directly or sobel of some gaussian filtered image) to be evaluated on the lines between those four points and corner features to be evaluated at those 4 points.

Additionally you can penalize unlikely rectangles (maybe depending on the angles between the points or on the distance to the image boundary).

Comment: thanks for advice, i will try that.. But i am wonder about time complexity. This probably will not working "real time" :].. but if there will be no other choice. This probably will be the result..

Comment: it's actually not that bad. Exploiting parallelization when computing the features at the point connections you should be able to do that below one second. The exhaustive search in the hough transform certainly has a higher complexity.

Comment: Hm, i tried that snake in FIJI (and more i tried level set), but it seems not accurate (and that if i do some "optimalization" and convert that image in black&white mask) and it takes too much times :/ (FIJI is slow, but this is really very slow)

Comment: i'd made the experience that active contours aren't viable for high-res pictures with a noisy environment and/or bad contrast.
the problem i see with the pictures of OP is that there are multiple edges and therefore a high energy. so that is disorting the snakes.